# Why the algorithm does not work in Maxima

Tags: javascript, algorithm, maxima

I have the algorithm program that works in JavaScript.

```js
var mas2 = [
        [1],
        [2],
        [3, 5, 7],
        [4],
        [],
        [6],
        [],
        [8],
        []
    ];
    var param = [20, 15, 15, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5];
    var out = [];
    var N = param.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) out[i] = recurs(i);
    alert(out);

    function recurs(i) {
        var f = param[i];
        if (mas2[i].length) {
            var Nc = mas2[i].length;
            for (var j = 0; j < Nc; j++) f += recurs(mas2[i][j])
        }
        return f
    }
```

I get out an array [80,60,45,10,5,10,5,10,5]
I translated this program into Maxima language, and it does not work as it should

```
    mas2:[[2],[3],[4,6,8],[5],[],[7],[],[9],[]]$ 
    param:[20,15,15,5,5,5,5,5,5]$
    recurs(i):=(
      f:param[i],
      if length(mas2[i])>0 then(
        Nc:length(mas2[i]),
        for j:1 thru Nc do(
          f:f+recurs(mas2[i][j])
        ) 
      ) ,f
    )$
    out:[]$ 
    N:length(param)$ for i:1 thru N do(out:append(out,[recurs(i)]));
```

I get out a list [60,40,25,10,5,10,5,10,5]. Why?

Comment: Found a solution  recurs(i):=block([f,j,Nc], ....

Comment: you could answer your own question, if you like.

Comment: Yes please do that